# Login loop after update

Tags: login

I installed the latest updates for 18.04 then restarted to apply the updates. When I tried to login it would just return to the login page again. I tried the instructions from this video

https://youtu.be/OG4deLa_vK8

and from this post

[Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

So when i do ctrl+alt+f3, login, run 'ls -la' then run 'sudo chown username:username .Xauthority' it just says 'chown: cannot access '.Xauthority' : no such file or directory'

I dont know what to do next.

Comment: when you ran `ls -la` did you see `.Xauthority` on the list? If the list was too long and you can't scroll back use `ls -la .X*` instead.